# Getting error An expression of type 'void' cannot be tested for truthiness angular 7

Tags: datepicker, node-modules, angular7

```
ERROR in node_modules\@ng-bootstrap\ng-bootstrap\datepicker\datepicker-navigation.d.ts.NgbDatepickerNavigation.html(3,67): : An expression of type 'void' cannot be tested for truthiness
node_modules\@ng-bootstrap\ng-bootstrap\datepicker\datepicker-navigation.d.ts.NgbDatepickerNavigation.html(25,67): : An expression of type 'void' cannot be tested for truthiness
```

when i am using ng build --prod i am getting this error

Answer (score 0):

look at this issue: https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/issues/2755 , you need to update ur ng-bootstrap to actual version or fix it with the answer, decribed on

Answer (score 0):

upgrade to ngb-3.1.1. This issue has been taken care.
https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/issues/2826